# Why won't this program print?

Tags: java, for-loop, printing

The problem is to determine the number of hours required before the second method becomes more beneficial than the first. I've been looking at this all day and don't know why I can't get it to print.

```
 public class BestMethod{
    
      public static void main(String[] args){
    
    double earnings1 = 10.00;
    double earnings2 = 0.10;
    double totalHours1 = 0;
    double totalHours2 = 0;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    
    {
      totalHours1++;
        x = totalHours1 * earnings1;
    
      totalHours2++;
        earnings2 *= 1;
          y = (earnings2 * 1) * 2 + earnings2;
        }
    
      if (y > x){
        System.out.println ("It will take the second method " + totalHours2 + " hours before it becomes more beneficial than the first method ");
       }
    
     }
    }
```

Comment: Becase `x = 100.0` and `y = 0.30000000000000004`. So, `y` is not greater than `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, the value of `earnings1` and `earnings2` are remaining the same.

After the first iteration `(i = 1)` how values are changing (use pen and paper)

`totalHours1 = 1.0`, `totalHours2 = 1.0`, `x = 10.0` and `y = 0.30000000000000004`

After completing the loop `(i = 10)`

`totalHours1 = 10.0`, `totalHours2 = 10.0`, `x = 100.0` and `y = 0.30000000000000004`

So, the value of `y` is less than the value of `x` and the condition is going to `false`.

So, (in case if you want to) print the value use this in your program `if (y < x)` or you have to change the mathematical (calculation) method.

Comment: @Gia  If you find this helpful, don't forget to accept the answer!